# how can I get a trapeze image without distorting the image?

Tags: css, image, css-shapes

I'm trying to present the image in a trapeze form without messing with the actual image nor using skew. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "trapeze form"? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the border trick but couldn't make the image appear in only one border maintaining the trapeze effect. also tried using this http://jsfiddle.net/ceGGN/38/ but it distorts the image.. I need it to stay as if I just cut one edge

Comment: Well, make it clearer next time, and provide the fiddle in the question. I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a canvas for this resulting in this:

[image: From demo]

## [Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ceGGN/119/)

A simple adjustment of the **HTML** to use a canvas instead:

```
<div class="box">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Remove some of the **CSS** rule specifications:

```
.box{
    height:300px;  
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box > canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And add this in the **JavaScript** section:

```
var img = new Image,
    ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

/// load image dynamically (or use an existing image in DOM)
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'http://cssglobe.com/lab/angled/img.jpg';

function draw() {

    /// set canvas size = image size
    var w, h;
    canvas.width = w = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = h = this.naturalHeight;

    /// draw the trapez shape
    ctx.moveTo(0, h * 0.25);
    ctx.lineTo(w, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(w, h);
    ctx.lineTo(0, h * 0.75);

    /// make it solid
    ctx.fill();

    /// change composite mode to replace the solid shape
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

    /// draw in image
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}
```

This works in all modern browsers. If that's not needed then palpatim's approach is quicker.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "trapezoidal" image, ry using `clip-path`:

```
img {
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  -o-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/ceGGN/114/

**NOTE**: Browser support isn't great for this, so make sure you test it thoroughly, or can accept a degraded performance on other browsers. Otherwise, the surest way to accomplish this is to edit your image to use a PNG with transparent background along your clip path.

Comment: thank you!! hope can make it work in most browsers. the thing is I need to make it in a way that the user can upload a new image without having to edit it first..